# Map over object preserving keys

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

The `map` function in underscore.js, if called with a javascript object, returns an array of values mapped from the object's values.

```
_.map({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}, function(num, key){ return num * 3; });
=> [3, 6, 9]
```

is there a way to make it preserve the keys? ie, I want a function that returns

```
{one: 3, two: 6, three: 9}
```

Comment: If you, like me, came here looking for a 'mapValues' like function that changes the actual object instead of returning a new one, check this simple solution out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894044/destructively-map-object-properties-function

Answer (score 256, accepted):

With **Underscore**

Underscore provides a function [`_.mapObject`](http://underscorejs.org/#mapObject) to map the values and preserve the keys.

```
_.mapObject({ one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }, function (v) { return v * 3; });

// => { one: 3, two: 6, three: 9 }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tANuM/81)**</kbd>

---

With **Lodash**

Lodash provides a function [`_.mapValues`](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues) to map the values and preserve the keys.

```
_.mapValues({ one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }, function (v) { return v * 3; });

// => { one: 3, two: 6, three: 9 }
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rgzsu1tL/1)**</kbd>

Comment: There have been efforts to get a _.mapValues function into underscore: [Relevant Issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/220), [Pull Request for _.mapValues](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/pull/1953). I hope this goes through :)

Comment: it looks to me like you're making an OBJECT into an object, or am i out of my mind?

Comment: @jsh In this case, `_.map()` is returning `[['one', 3], ['two', 6], ['three', 9]]`, which is an array of arrays, and `_.object()` is turning it back into an object.

Answer (score 59):

I managed to find the required function in lodash, a utility library similar to underscore.

http://lodash.com/docs#mapValues

> ```
> _.mapValues(object, [callback=identity], [thisArg])
> ```
>
> Creates an object with the same keys as object and values generated by
>    running each own enumerable property of object through the callback.
>    The callback is bound to thisArg and invoked with three arguments;
>   (value, key, object).

Answer (score 20):

How about this version in plain JS (**ES6 / ES2015**)?

```
let newObj = Object.assign(...Object.keys(obj).map(k => ({[k]: obj[k] * 3})));
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cakapiyapo/1/edit?html,js,console)

If you want to map over an object **recursively** (map nested obj), it can be done like this:

```
const mapObjRecursive = (obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') obj[key] = mapObjRecursive(obj[key]);
    else obj[key] = obj[key] * 3;
  });
  return obj;
};
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/basoyafapu/1/edit?html,js,console)

Since **ES7 / ES2016** you can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) instead of `Object.keys` like this:

```
let newObj = Object.assign(...Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v * 3})));
```

And since **ES2019** you can use  [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```
let newObj = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => ([k, v * 3])))
```

Answer (score 19):

```js
var mapped = _.reduce({ one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }, function(obj, val, key) {
    obj[key] = val*3;
    return obj;
}, {});

console.log(mapped);
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 13):

I know this is old, but now Underscore has a new map for objects :

```
_.mapObject(object, iteratee, [context])
```

You can of course build a flexible map for both arrays and objects

```
_.fmap = function(arrayOrObject, fn, context){
    if(this.isArray(arrayOrObject))
      return _.map(arrayOrObject, fn, context);
    else
      return _.mapObject(arrayOrObject, fn, context);
}
```

Comment: Note to lodash users: jdalton has decided to [break compatibility with underscore.js](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/980) over this change. lodash will not support `mapObject`; look at lodash's `mapValues` method instead.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been a long time, but still the most obvious solution via fold (aka reduce in js) is missing, for the sake of completeness i'll leave it here:

```
function mapO(f, o) {
  return Object.keys(o).reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = f(o[key])
    return acc
  }, {})
}
```

Comment: I am okay with the use of Lodash library but programmers are using these kind of libraries, and not knowing how this things could be achieved in vanilla JS. So, I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 3):

[_.map](http://underscorejs.org/#map) returns an Array, not an Object.

If you want an object you're better off using a different function, like `each`; if you really want to use map you could do something like this:

```
Object.keys(object).map(function(value, index) {
   object[value] *= 3;
})
```

but that is confusing, when seeing `map` one would expect to have an array as result and then make something with it.

Comment: I had a feeling reading the docs that it wouldn't be natural to try this in underscore.js. I think my use case is quite natural, why don't they support it?

Comment: One reason could likely be that `map` is used to change an input producing an array as output, you could compose `_.object` and `_.map` as @GG. wrote, but that's a matter of taste at this point.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a [mapValues](http://lodash.com/docs#mapValues) function (to map a function over the values of an object), which is easy enough to implement yourself:

```
mapValues = function(obj, f) {
  var k, result, v;
  result = {};
  for (k in obj) {
    v = obj[k];
    result[k] = f(v);
  }
  return result;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const mapObject = (obj = {}, mapper) =>
  Object.entries(obj).reduce(
    (acc, [key, val]) => ({ ...acc, [key]: mapper(val) }),
    {},
  );
```

Comment: I was about to add this answer myself. Glad I scrolled!

Answer (score 1):

_.map using lodash  like loop to achieve this

```
 var result={};
_.map({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}, function(num, key){ result[key]=num * 3; });
console.log(result)

//output
{one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}
```

Reduce is clever looks like above answare

```
_.reduce({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}, function(result, num, key) {
  result[key]=num * 3
  return result;
}, {});

//output
{one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

**A mix fix** for the underscore map *bug* :P

```
_.mixin({ 
    mapobj : function( obj, iteratee, context ) {
        if (obj == null) return [];
        iteratee = _.iteratee(iteratee, context);
        var keys = obj.length !== +obj.length && _.keys(obj),
            length = (keys || obj).length,
            results = {},
            currentKey;
        for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
          currentKey = keys ? keys[index] : index;
          results[currentKey] = iteratee(obj[currentKey], currentKey, obj);
        }
        if ( _.isObject( obj ) ) {
            return _.object( results ) ;
        } 
        return results;
    }
});
```

A simple workaround that keeps the right key and return as object 
It is still used the same way as i guest you could used this function 
to override the bugy _.map function

or simply as me used it as a mixin

```
_.mapobj ( options , function( val, key, list )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.mapValues(users, function(o) { return o.age; });` in Lodash and `_.mapObject({ one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }, function (v) { return v * 3; });` in Underscore.

Check out the cross-documentation here: http://jonathanpchen.com/underdash-api/#mapvalues-object-iteratee-identity