# How to convert a property inside an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have this: `[{id: '1', name: 'name1'},{id: '2', name: 'name2'}...]`

I would like to convert the `id` field to an integer instead of a string. What’s the most elegant way of doing it using loash?

Comment: The "most elegant way" is a matter of opinion. What's wrong with the way you're doing it currently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map over object preserving keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023226/map-over-object-preserving-keys) — it’s effectively this but with `return Number(v);`.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the array with [`_.forEach()`](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach) and convert the ID to an integer with `parseInt()`.

```
_.forEach(yourArray, function(obj) {
    obj.id = parseInt(obj.id, 10);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with lodash
but if it's not an issue with your syntax then make a temporary array for storage and use [parse int](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't lodash but you can do this easily in vanilla ES6:

```
const newArr = oldArr.map(({id, name}) => ({id: Number(id), name});
```

https://repl.it/@RemLampa/WiltedHospitablePatch