# preserve object keys using .map in native JS

Tags: javascript

I would like to keep object keys when reducing a CSV data set using JavaScript's map function (if this is in fact the right approach?)

I have read [a top SO thread on preserving keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023226/map-over-object-preserving-keys), but the solutions given require external JS libraries (underscore or lodash).  I'd prefer avoiding anything but 'vanila' JS if possible.

For example:

```
var basket = [{fruit: "apple", veg: "carrot", nut: "peanut"},
 {fruit: "pear", veg: "lettuce", nut: "pistachio"},
 {fruit: "banana", veg: "radish", nut: "pecan"},
 {fruit: "kiwi", veg: "kale", nut: "almond"}]
```

Yields an array of 3 objects, corresponding to each 'food type' entry above (fruit, veg, nut).

I don't want nuts, so I try using map to filter them out:

```
var small_basket = basket.map(function(item){
  return [
item.fruit,
item.veg
  ]
});
```

This approach returns an array of 4 arrays, corresponding to each of the items per food type in my list, e.g. 4 fruits and 4 nuts (so we've effectively eliminated nuts).

My trouble is: now my object keys are gone! Instead, my array now looks like this:

```
small_basket = Array(3) [
  0: Array(2) [
  0: "apple"
  1: "carrot"
]
  1: Array(2) [
  0: "pear"
  1: "lettuce"
]
  2: Array(2) [
  0: "bananna"
  1: "raddish"
]
]
```

**What can I do differently to preserve object keys?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just return another object:

```
return {
  fruit: item.fruit,
  veg: item.veg
}
```

That can be shortly written as:

```
 array.map(({ fruit, veg }) => ({ fruit, veg }))
```

or if you don't want to duplicate identifiers:

```
 const pick = (key, ...rest) => obj => key ? ({ [key]: obj[key], ...pick(...rest)(obj) }): {};
 array.map(pick("fruit", "veg"))
```

or to invert the *extraction* into a *removal*:

```
 array.map(({ nut, ...rest }) => rest)
```

Comment: The removal [ `...rest` ] approach is terrific for not having to repeat the object key values that I wish to retain on both sides of the arrow function, but it's working from the opposite end: stating which variables to delete. It doesn't appear from the several answers to my question that there's a way to specify only once the list of key values one wishes to retain. Is there?

Comment: @aaron.kyle that is only possible with a helper.

Answer (score 2):

From the `.map` callback, return an object containing the keys you want, instead of returning an array:

```js
var basket = [{fruit: "apple", veg: "carrot", nut: "peanut"},
 {fruit: "pear", veg: "lettuce", nut: "pistachio"},
 {fruit: "banana", veg: "radish", nut: "pecan"},
 {fruit: "kiwi", veg: "kale", nut: "almond"}]

var small_basket = basket.map(({ fruit, veg }) => ({ fruit, veg }));
console.log(small_basket);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the map functions, the returning value is always the child of your Array. In you case, you should return a Object, because your child element in Array is Object, returning array will make your child element was map to array.

I think the code below will match you needs:

```
basket.map(function(item){
  return { fruit: item.fruit, veg: item.veg }
});
```

That is so reduntant. Using ES 6 [Destucting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Setting_a_function_parameter's_default_value), you may simply write like this:

```
basket.map(function({ nut, fruits, veg}){
  return { fruits, veg }
});
```

But the way above will be not much elasticity, using ES 6 [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), you may simply write like this:

```
basket.map(function({ nut, ...restFoodType }){
  return { ...restFoodType }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you want to keep the ref and know how delete works:

```
var basket = [{
    fruit: "apple",
    veg: "carrot",
    nut: "peanut"
  },
  {
    fruit: "pear",
    veg: "lettuce",
    nut: "pistachio"
  },
  {
    fruit: "banana",
    veg: "radish",
    nut: "pecan"
  },
  {
    fruit: "kiwi",
    veg: "kale",
    nut: "almond"
  }
];

basket.forEach(x => delete x.nut);

console.log(basket)
```