# How to translate one typescript class object to another, where only values change and keys are left unchanged?

Tags: typescript, class, interface, mapping

I have two classes/interfaces:

```ts
class ImageObjectsJson {
    [markerId : string] : WktGeometryJson[];
}

class ImageObjects {
    [markerId : string] : ImageObject[]
}
```

I know the contructor of ImageObject which takes WktGeometryJson object as a parameter. So I can call:

```ts
const wkt : WktGeometryJson = {... something useful here ...};
const imageObject : ImageObject = new ImageObject(wkt);
```

How to create ImageObjects, having ImageObjectsJson, leaving keys unchanged?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [map function for objects (instead of arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays)

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure... :) In the mentioned answer, they are transforming values to the same type (numbers). I want to cast values to a different type specified by the second interface. I will look again, whether I can return a different type.

Comment: Yes, final versions of the Answer post, with ES6 look quite good actually. Thanks!

Comment: Also it seems a good - probably a better - answer is here (using lodash): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023226/map-over-object-preserving-keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example - on top of [map function for objects (instead of arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810506/map-function-for-objects-instead-of-arrays)

```ts
interface WktGeometryJson {
  name: string
}

class ImageObject {
  imageName: string;

  constructor(json: WktGeometryJson) {
    this.imageName = json.name;
  }
}

class ImageObjectsJson {
    [markerId : string] : WktGeometryJson[];
}

class ImageObjects {
    [markerId : string] : ImageObject[]
}

const imJson: ImageObjectsJson= {
  aaa: [{name: '1'}, {name: '2'}],
  bbb: [{name: '3'}]
}

const imObj = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(imJson).map(
    ([propName, wktArray]) => [propName, wktArray.map(wkt => new ImageObject(wkt))]
  )
);

console.log(imObj);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOoGswHEIHsC2EYUAngFIDOuIyA3gFDLIhyEBcyFxoA5vQL716CADZwKFZAEl8cHhADyAIwBWEBGDqNkwWfIByrCBy5ReAbiFME1UwFcNuKAAoVVEBwzY8hYuXcAlFpMTGAAFsAUAHS6chCGhMgAvMhu1FEshJZMgoLCYhLSeoqq6mAUlNTBIQDaslDo0FIAJsgm3CA8ALptaJg4BESklSA1XZZ5ouKSMnHKahqSDCHIdXANTa3tZp09HLPy82VjAkI2IFw6%20CP7xUeLIynLyHCvHDW0mcbIAOQAjD9%20AAaOhfDg-ABMgK6QO0Snh70%20RnBAGZoadhLZNLp5slkPcwFEYFACABRcBmCAUZzaAlRCAU4BU5y6EYBKKyAAONJWzhqnJJnISEBBAHdMABBKBQOAkLpBJIAPlWAtwQqMYsl0tlHLg3PFmiVzAgoqKc1KGmcBoCAS62gC9AClkxF1wIggUREuB4LPw8ydQiAA)

Comment: Tried to implement it myself, but I missed something... Your version works! Thank You :)